# How create a custom componemt in Qt 6.2?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I've been having that problem since I upgrade my Qt to **6.2 version**.
If I create a project in **5.15 version** (like the project "**untitled1**" in the picture) I can create a new QML component ("**Meutexto.qml**" file) and call that in the main file. But, if I create the same thing in a 6.2 version project ("**untitled**"), I got the error: `qrc:/untitled/main.qml:9:5: Meutexto is not a type`.

The 6.2 version create a QML projec folder automatically and the 5.15 version use the Resources project folder to QML files. Can that problem be related to that?

**More details:**

I am having problem with the example in the picture and code below. I got that error in Qt 6.2:`QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component qrc:/untitled/main.qml:9:5: Meutexto is not a type`. I don't get that error with the 5.15 version.

[image: Project files]

[image]

Code of **main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Meutexto {}
}
```

Code of **Meutexto.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "My Text"
    }
}
```

Code of **untitle.pro**:

```
QT += quick

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

resources.files = main.qml 
resources.prefix = /$${TARGET}
RESOURCES += resources \
    qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    Meutexto.qml
```

Code of **qml.qrc**:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>Meutexto.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Your Meutexto.qml file should be added to a resource file (.qrc).

Comment: @JarMan I've already tried that, the error was the same.

Comment: Then please provide a [mre].

Comment: @JarMan I edited to show the complete project.

Comment: You did not provide your qml.qrc file.

Comment: @JarMan I added another image

Comment: Please don't provide code as images. A [mre] should be something I can copy directly and run myself to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @JarMan here:
 
 <RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>Meutexto.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide your main.cpp file, but I created a new project and noticed the default one that it generates uses a URL that looks like this:

```
const QUrl url(u"qrc:/my_project/main.qml"_qs);
```

It makes more sense to me to change it to this:

```
const QUrl url(u"qrc:/main.qml"_qs);
```

After that change, there are two ways to make your code work:

1. Use the qml.qrc file the same way you did in Qt 5.15. With the change in main.cpp, You should not need to make any changes in your .qrc file.

untitled.pro:

```
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

2. The other method seems to be a new way to automatically create resource files from within a .pro file. I'm not as familiar with this method, but it's documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#qmake). In your .pro file, do this:

```
resources.files = \
    main.qml \
    Meutexto.qml
resources.prefix = /
RESOURCES += resources
```

This looks a little bit nicer since you no longer need to manually create a .qrc file.